# Working examples of winform/WPF apps

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-interface

I'm a user interface designer.  The project I'm working on is a dashboard that will have several interactive and customizable widgets (think Netvibes, etc.). The development group is going to be using either WinForm or WPF to build the dashboard and widgets. I need to understand the capabilities of each technology better and see a sampling of actual working apps to help accomplish this.  I can't download and build examples... need live examples somewhere on the web.  Can you point me to live, existing apps?  Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Microsoft's site about Windows Forms and WPF: http://windowsclient.net/
WPF Showcase gallery: http://windowsclient.net/community/showcase.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I really liked looking through a sample program called [Kevin's Bag-o-tricks](http://j832.com/bagotricks/), which does a really good job of highlighting some of the best features of wpf.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you an idea of some of the cababilities of WPF:
http://xamples.infragistics.com/2008.2/xamShowcase.xbap

Although it loads in the Browser, all of these examples can be run as independent apps.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the apps coming from [thirteen23.com](http://www.thirteen23.com)  Blu is a nice WPF Twitter client.  I don't care for the app itself, but it does a nice job of showing off what WPF can do.  Compare that to your standard "Developer Art" WinForms app and you should have a pretty good idea of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Hypershot and Hyperdrive from Bunkspeed (http://www.bunkspeed.com/index.html) are WPF applications.